# How to use powershell to set the property for PasswordRevealMode of a passwordBox [WPF]

Tags: powershell, properties, passwordbox

i want to know how to use a checkbox to show or hide the password in a passwordBox with powershell (using WPF). I have found many examples about c# but i can't get it working with powershell. How do we set the paswordrevealmode property in powershell to "hidden" or "visible" ?

in c# this is done like that:

```
    private void CheckBox_Changed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (revealModeCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        passwordBox1.PasswordRevealMode = PasswordRevealMode.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        passwordBox1.PasswordRevealMode = PasswordRevealMode.Hidden;
    }
}
```

i know i'm missing something here, i am still learning wpf with powershell :)

The code i am working with is the following:

```
function Get-Info () {
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = @'
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Informations requises" Height="161.4" Width="544.4">
    <Grid>
        <Label Name="label" Content="Est-ce que le serveur *** est local, saas ou cloud ?" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF1843BA" FontWeight="Bold" Width="296" />
        <Label Name="label1" Content="Mot de passe genere dans *** :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="12,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Foreground="#FF1843BA" FontWeight="Bold">
            <Label.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform />
                    <SkewTransform />
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0.035" />
                    <TranslateTransform />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Label.RenderTransform>
        </Label>
        <TextBox Name="tbIndex" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="94,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="203" />
        <Label Name="label2" Content="Index Client:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF1843BA" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Label Name="label3" Content="Adresse IP:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.202,0.727" Foreground="#FF1843BA" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Label Name="label7" Content="DNS Restreint ?" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="302,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF1843BA" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Button Name="btSave" Content="Enregistrer les informations" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="326,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" RenderTransformOrigin="0.501,-0.221" Height="23" />
        <StackPanel Name="spServerType" Height="28" Margin="306,7,-18.8,0"  Width="212" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <RadioButton Name="rbCloud" Content="Cloud" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="Serveur" Margin="5" />
            <RadioButton Name="rbServerLocal" Content="Serveur Local" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91" GroupName="Serveur" Margin="5" />
            <RadioButton Name="rbSaas" Content="SaaS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="Serveur" Margin="5" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="spDNS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="405,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RadioButton Name="rbDnsYes" Content="Oui" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="DNS" Margin="5" />
            <RadioButton Name="rbDnsNo" Content="Non" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="DNS" Margin="5" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="tbIP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="94,96,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="204" />
        <StackPanel Name="spPassword" Margin="254,32,8.4,67" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <PasswordBox Name="pbPassword" Width="245" Margin="0,1,0,1" />
            <CheckBox Name="revealModeCheckBox" Content="" IsChecked="False" ToolTip="Show password" Margin="6,6" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

#Read XAML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Some possible causes for this problem include: .NET Framework is missing PowerShell must be launched with PowerShell -sta, invalid XAML code was encountered."; exit}

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

## Item1
$revealModeCheckBox.Add_Checked({
    #***this is the part i have trouble with*** 
    $pbPassword.PasswordRevealMode = "PasswordRevealMode.Visible"
})

$btSave.Add_Click({
$global:hastable = @{}
    #get the password as SecureString
    $hastable.add( "Password", ($pbPassword.securePassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString))
    $form.Close()

})

$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
return $Global:hastable
}

get-info
```

i have tried multiple values for the property PasswordRevealMode as shown below:

```
$revealModeCheckBox.Add_Checked({
    #***this is the part i have trouble with*** 
    $pbPassword.PasswordRevealMode = 1
})
```

or

```
$revealModeCheckBox.Add_Checked({
    #***this is the part i have trouble with*** 
    $pbPassword.PasswordRevealMode = $true
})
```

it seems it is not the right way to set this property in powershell.. i got the following errors doing so:

```
The property 'PasswordRevealMode' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\git\temp\Samplescript.ps1:54 char:5
+     $pbPassword.PasswordRevealMode = "PasswordRevealMode.Visible"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

or

```
The property 'PasswordRevealMode' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\git\temp\Samplescript.ps1:54 char:5
+     $pbPassword.PasswordRevealMode = 1
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

or

```
The property 'PasswordRevealMode' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\git\temp\Samplescript.ps1:54 char:5
+     $pbPassword.PasswordRevealMode = $true
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

the actual GUI looks like that:

[image]

i have found a work around using a popup message to show the password but what i am trying to do is to show it using the passwordBox as described here:

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.passwordrevealmode)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So I looked at the documentation and by default the passwordbox control is supposed to have a button on it that allows the reveal. If yours does not then there is something else going on. First, do you explicitly import Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls in your code?

Comment: I don't think so .. i was thinking that it is a part of the presentationframework, How do you import it then ?

Comment: @jiciftw I think it's not possible as there is no PasswordRevealMode property in WPF PasswordBox. It seems that property is available for Universal Windows Platform apps and not Powershell GUI. When I try to force this property it says that `System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox.PasswordRevealMode` is unknown.

Comment: With a regular textbox in Windows Forms you can use a character to mask the actual input characters to get masked password entry.

Comment: isn't it better for security to use a passwordBox ? the password is given as a securestring, is there a difference between that and using a textbox and then convert it to a secure string ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.